# FIFA World Cup 2014 final ranking rules

Tags: rules, football, world-cup

I have tried to find the final ranking rules for the FIFA World Cup 2014.

What are the rules to rank teams after the tournament finished?

Comment: Are you asking for the ranking after the world cup, or the final standing inside the cup?

Answer (score 3):

read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Rankings
It explains the system FIFA uses to asses points. There are many different multipliers, but if you read the section titled Match status you'll see that the the points of World Cup matches are multiplied by 4, where Continental cup matches are multiplied by 3, cup qualifiers match points are multiplied by 2 and friendly matched have multiplier 1.

Comment: I don't think the question is about the world rankings, but rather how the thirty-two teams who compete in the World Cup Finals are ranked at the end of the tournament.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the final World Cup standings; first, how the teams are grouped together, and second, how they're ranked within their groups.

### Grouping

Teams knocked out in the same phase of the tournament are grouped together and ranked against each other. In practice, this could mean that a team eliminated at an earlier stage will be ranked lower than a team that advanced to a later stage, despite having more points. (For example, see the [2006 final standings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup#Final_standings), where Spain (9 points, 9th place) ended with more points than Ukraine (7 points, 8th place).) Thus there are four groups of teams:

- teams 17-32 (eliminated in the group stage)
- teams 9-16 (eliminated in the round of 16)
- teams 5-8 (eliminated in the quarterfinals)
- teams 1-4 (reached the semi-finals)

### Ranking

The tiebreakers (for teams 17-32, 9-16, and 5-8) are the same as are used to determine which teams advanced from the group stage:

1. Total points earned
2. Goal differential
3. Goals scored
4. Number of points obtained in matches between tied teams
5. Goal difference in matches between tied teams
6. Number of goals scored in matches between tied teams

Teams still tied after the sixth tiebreaker would be listed as sharing the given rank. See the [2006 final standings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup#Final_standings), where Iran and the United States are listed as tied for 25th.

Teams 1-4 are ranked based on the results of the final and third-place game.